# python class and dir() function

Tags: python

I created an empty class in python and i put that class name to `dir()` (`dir(A)`) function then it returned output like this:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__eq__',
 '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__',
 '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__',
 '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', 
 '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__']
```

So I want to know from where those things came from??

Comment: You should have formatted your output as code

Comment: See [special method names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of them comes from `object`, which all classes inherit from.
But some are set when defining the new class.

```
set(dir(A)) - set(dir(object))

{'__dict__', '__module__', '__weakref__'}
```

So these three does not come from `object`.

Comment: An,, Ha,,,!!   it seems like Object class in Java.. Thanks for your answer!!